# Блокировка перехода с определенного сайта

Tags: nginx, apache2

Опишите вариант по блокировке перехода с определенного сайта по рефереру для Nginx ну и для Apache2

Comment: какой смысл вы вкладываете в слово «блокировка»?

Comment: Ну нужно запретить переходы с определенного сайта, спарсили сайт разместили на своем ресурсе ссылки на страницы моего сайта, это может повлиять на позиции в выдаче

Comment: как вы представляете себе «запрет перехода» на ваш сайт? что должно при этом произойти?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел ответ для nginx в конфиге в секции Server

```
if ($http_referer ~* "site\.ru") {
return 403;
}
```

для Apache2

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://www\.site\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Comment: nginx: то есть при переходе с asite.ru пользователь тоже увидит 403?

Comment: ну не тоже, а только с этого сайта

Comment: нет, при таком `if` 403 получат все пользователи в рефере которых, в любом его месте, содержится site.ru

Comment: ну и классно, главное что проблема решена